# convert Visual Basic loop to C# loop

Tags: c#, .net

How it could be converted to C#?

```
For i = IBase36.Length - 1 To 0 Step i - 1

Next
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why didn't you even attempt to do this on your own.  Heck...There are hundreds of FREE Visual Basic .NET to C# converters online

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (int i = IBase36.Length -1; i >=0; i--)
{
    //Your Treatment
}
```

Comment: Please look at what the OP is "stepping" by and this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx

Comment: The article leads me to believe that the `i--` should instead be `i += i - 1`

Comment: No I don't think, because you decrement, it's just instruction

Comment: `i-1` is equal to `i--` folks.  `i+=i -1` doubles `i` then subtracts one.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the clear response. I suppose it's because I haven't actually used VB. I'm mostly confused by the second example (in my link above). It is clear (because the OP accepted the answer) that the OP meant `i--`. Did the OP simply type that wrong? Or does VB have some sort of special construct regarding using `i` itself in the step portion of the `for...next` construct? Looking at the construct(format?) from the link, the appropriate "step" to put would be `-1`. I'm just curious.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
for (int i = IBase36.Length -1; i >=0; i--)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```